# Aligning text in center when wrapped in a View in React Native not working

Tags: css, react-native

Making a notification bubble for messages, but text is not centering. 
Here is my code:

```
<View style = {{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', position: 'absolute', top: -5, right: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'red', height: h, width: w, borderRadius: br}}>

            <Text style = {{fontSize: 10, color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                {'7'}
            </Text>
</View>
```

And here is the result: 
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4kos.jpg)

Comment: Add flex:1 to your container

Answer (score 1):

Try alignSelf: center in your text style